# passing a grep list as an argument to cp

Tags: bash, unix, grep, cp

lets say I want to copy a list of files to another directory

```
-rw-rw----    Sep 1 11:06   File1.txt
-rw-rw----    Sep 1 11:06   File101.txt
-rw-rw----    Sep 3 11:06   File2.txt    
-rw-rw----    Sep 4 11:06   File303.txt
```

I would like to grep all the files that have a Sep 1 in there

```
ls -lrt | grep 'Sep 1'
```

and try to pass it to cp as an argument

```
cp `ls -lrt | grep 'Sep 1'` /directory/
or
cp $(ls -lrt | grep 'Sep 1') /directory/
```

with the second option i that is an illegal variable name 
can you please help me with this?

Answer (score 4):

Do not parse the output of `ls`: [Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Instead, you can do something like:

```
cp *1* /directory/
```

This `*1*` will match anything containing `1` and will apply to the `cp` command, so that it will be expanded to something like:

```
cp File1.txt File2.txt File303.txt File101.txt /directory/
```

---

### Update

The first solution would be do to the following: print the file name after `grep`ping of those files whose modification time is `Sep 1`. Based on that output, copy:

```
cp $(ls -1 | awk '/Sep 1/{print $NF}') /directory/
```

But this is very fragile, because filenames with spaces won't be copied, as well as the general fact that parsing ls is a bad idea.

Instead, if you want to move files that were modified on last 24 hours, you can do this:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -mtime -1 -exec cp {} /directory/ \;
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
       performs the search           copies the matches to the dir
```

Or also add `-daystart` to match "created today", not last 24 hours: `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -daystart -mtime -1 ...`

Comment: I am using ls lrt and greping the list by date thefore I can't use this option any other suggestion?

Comment: Update your question with full information. Otherwise this gets confusing.

Comment: @tripleee fair enough, just changed it. Thanks!